# Mark multiple locations in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-maps

I am trying to mark several locations on maps which I am fetching from Database through a php code :

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php error_reporting(0);

 $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysql_select_db('easydoes');

$query = mysql_query('SELECT city,latitude,longitude FROM zip_codes LIMIT 0 , 30');



while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $val[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($val);

?>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<script>
var obj;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.post("markers.php",{},function(data){
    obj=JSON.parse(data);
    //alert(obj[0].city);
    initialize(obj);
  });

});
</script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/src/markerclusterer.js">
    </script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
var markers = [];
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( obj[i].latitude, obj[i].longitude);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: obj[i].city
  });
   markers.push(marker);
}
markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
          maxZoom: 12,
          gridSize: 40,
          styles: "Default"
        });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where am I going wrong ? I am pretty new to Jquery and Java Script .

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the following line:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

and put it outside the for loop.

If this doesn't work, please paste the console log in order to see what is failing.

Edit: Try this:

```
var myLat = 'lat.to.center.your.map';
var myLong = 'long.to.center.your.map';
var myLatlng= new google.maps.LatLng( myLat, myLong);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
    var poiLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng( obj[i].latitude, obj[i].longitude);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: poiLatLang ,
        map: map,
        title: obj[i].city
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

You where always defining a new map, with new options and a new center. Try this out in order to see if it works. The vars myLat and myLong should be the latitude and longitude where you want your map to be centered a the begining.

## EDIT 2

Checking at the log you have posted in your comment, I now see that the url you are loading from google is wrong, you are missing the apiKey and secretKey, Check out the following link in order to solve this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Nevertheless, the modifications in my first edit, you will have to apply them in order to make it work correctly.

Comment: This is the log in access.log `127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2013:09:15:00 +0530] "GET /Google%20Maps/markers_sample.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2013:09:15:00 +0530] "POST /Google%20Maps/markers.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2079`

Comment: This was the comment in apache_error.log `[Tue Dec 03 09:12:35 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache2, referer: http://localhost:81/Google%20Maps/
[Tue Dec 03 09:12:35 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache2, referer: http://localhost:81/Google%20Maps/`